# I want to get a message of "success" and redirect to /home ,but not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get a message of success and redirect the page to home,but this appears when I click the button [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3LSO.png)

my code :

```
     this.verifyCodeService.check_verification(verifyCode).subscribe((res) => {
     alert("Success")
     this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
   },(err)=>{
      alert(JSON.stringify(err))
   });
```

verifyCodeService :

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class VerifyCodeService {
  readonly baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth' ;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  check_verification(verify){
     console.log(verify);
    return this.http.put(this.baseURL+`/check_verification`, verify);

  }
}
```

Here is the Server :

```
exports.check_verification = (req, res) => {
    var verifyCode=req.body.code;
    if(verifyCode=vcode){
      const updatemodel=User.updateOne({ _id:req.body.user_id }, { $set: { verify_status:"Registered"} },)
      Promise.all([updatemodel]).then(() => {
      }).catch((err) =>{
        console.log(err);
      })
      res.send("/home");
    }else{
      console.log("fail");
      res.send("fail");
    }

  }
```

Comment: Looks like your verifyCodeService.check_verification method is throwing error .Please update code of check_verification

Comment: @RahulCv I have added verifyCodeService

Comment: Looks like your server is giving an error ,this.http.put(this.baseURL+`/check_verification`, verify); . Kindly check whether the method is PUT or POST

Comment: @RahulCv its PUT

Comment: @RahulCv added server method

Comment: Looks fine can u take a screen shot of your network Tab ,or can u give HAR file